# Java grab data from a specific arraylist, by entering the name?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say you have an array like this:

```
protected ArrayList<String> client = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then you do this:

```
client.add(ip, username);
```

What I am trying to do is, grab the username, using the IP.
I only have the IP, I don't have the username, and therefore I need to use the IP to grab the username.

The IP is unique, can't have the same ip in the same array.

***How can I use the IP to get the username?***

Comment: ["_Get out the map_...."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 6):

You should use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with `String` key and value instead, and use the `ip` as key. A basic example:

```
Map<String, String> clients = new HashMap<String, String>();

//fill the map...
String ip = "127.0.0.1";
String name = "luiggi";
clients.put(ip, name);

//get the username by ip
System.out.println(clients.get(ip));
```